# Communication between Windows service and Windows form application

Tags: c#, windows-services, ipc

I am working on a project which is a sort of file uploader. In the project, there are certain log files which are created by an application and saved in a particular folder. The content of these files is always text. The contents of these files are uploaded to the server and this task is done by a windows service. The service  reads the files one by one and then transfer their contents to the server.

Earlier this task used to be done by the application itself. But it was separated from application because it is possible that when the application is running the user is offline. So these files will remain pending for upload.

The advantage of using service is obvious that the user doesn't have to worry about upload thing. Whenever the user is connected to internet the service will take care of it.

Now the requirement is that when service uploads the contents of the file and the application via which the files are created is running at that time, the service should send a message to the application that which file's content is being uploaded.

Now the problem is that the service and the application are not communicating. I've spawn seperate threads from both service and application which are using namedpipes for communication.

Here is the code which I've tried.

Service code:

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
Thread t;
    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        File.WriteAllText("D:\\log.txt", "Service started.\n");
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Connection);
        t = new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();
    }

    void Connection()
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("server");
        server.WaitForConnection();
        File.WriteAllText("D:\\log.txt", "Connection established.");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (t.IsAlive)
        {
            t.Abort();
            File.AppendAllText("D:\\log.txt", "Service stopped.");
        }
    }
}
```

Application code:

```
public delegate void SendMsg(string s);
public partial class UI : Form
{
    Thread t;

    public UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Waiting...";
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Connection);
        t = new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();
    }

    void DisplayMsg(string s)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = s;
    }

    void Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream("server");
            SendMsg msg = new SendMsg(DisplayMsg);
            msg("Connecting...");
            client.Connect();
            msg("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("D:\\log.txt", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this piece of code?

The same logic works if I use another form application in place of service.

While googling about this, I came to know about Session 0 in Windows Vista onward versions of Windows which is used specially for windows services and is isolated from the other sessions used by logged on users. I'm using Windows 8 in my system. Can this be a problem? Please explain in detail.

Comment: What's wrong with MMFs? They are faster than named pipes and are free from glitches of named pipes.

Comment: The code is just utterly broken.  It tries to create *two* servers, repeatedly with a timer.  And deletes the data before the client can ever read it.  Get rid of the timer, it makes no sense.  Only create the pipe server once.

Comment: Not sure why the votes to close.  This seems like a perfectly valid question for SO.

Comment: I've edited my question. I removed timer and used namedpipes only. But still the service and application is not communicating.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I'm not much of an expert on named pipes.  My only experience with them is via the [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (WCF), and I've had intermittent problems with them, albeit perhaps because I'm doing something wrong.  So I cannot speak intelligently to your named pipe problem.  I do know that when [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) chimes in with a word of advice, it is usually best to heed it.

All that said, if you expect the communication requirements to remain simple, there's nothing wrong with using named pipes (sockets, memory-mapped files, etc.).  Of course, if the communication between the service and application is expected to grow, it might make sense to consider something more formal like WCF.